# Проверка строки на содержание слов из массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

Возможно вопрос покажется глупым. У меня есть массив матерных слов и есть строка. Мне нужно узнать, содержит ли строка именно слова из массива.

```
let array = ['привет','пока']
let str = 'пока'
let str2 = str.split(' ')
```

Comment: вроде наоборот, есть ли в массиве слово из строки, не?

Comment: ну, можно и так

Comment: @Jean-Claude зачем мне php, если у меня js?)

Comment: пардон, https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let badWords = ['привет','пока']
let str = 'пока    показ     пивет';
let rule=/\s{1,}/g;
let stringParts = str.split(rule); 

let hasWord = false;
stringParts.forEach(word => {
    if (badWords.includes(word))
        hasWord = true;     
});

if (hasWord) 
    console.log('В строке есть слово из массива')
else 
    console.log('Слова не обнаружены')
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще такой вариант, если не использовать RegEx.

```js
let array = ['привет', 'пока']
let target = 'пока привет показ ';
let words = target.split(' ').filter(s => s !== '')

const isArrayIncludesTarget = words.some(word => {
    return array.includes(word);
});

console.log(isArrayIncludesTarget)
```